# Website Not Downloading PDF Created By Site C# / ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I have a website deployed on Hostgator. This is my first site so I'm still a little new to all this.  Using Visual Studio 2019 this works completely fine in development but once deployed on my site it throws an error:

**.../CreateRateConfirmation?loadNumber=RT222398 500 (Internal Server Error) VM1795 jquery:1**

I'm using itext v.7 to create the pdf, and I'm thinking it might have to do with my path when creating the pdf?  The actual pdf function is over 1800 lines of code so I am not going to post all that, but this is the relevant (I think) info:

```
string fileName = loads[i].Carrier.carrierName + " " + loadNumber + " Rate Confirmation.pdf";
                    string desktopFolder = "C:";
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(desktopFolder + "\\Rate Confirmations");
                    string downloadFolder = desktopFolder + "\\Rate Confirmations";

                    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(downloadFolder + "\\" + fileName);
                    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
                    Document document = new Document(pdf);
```

... *roughly a billion lines of pdf creation*...

```
                    document.Close();

                    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(downloadFolder + "\\" + fileName);
                    string timeStamp = getTimeStamp(name);
                    loads[i].notes = loads[i].notes + timeStamp + ": Rate Confirmation Created^";
                    db.Entry(loads[i]).CurrentValues.SetValues(loads[i]);
                    db.SaveChanges();

                    break;
```

For what it's worth the function has a timestamp in it that should show up in the notes on my site as well and it's not, so it clearly is not making it all the way through this function.

I'm sure this is a completely easy solution but I'm really new to all this and I just can't seem to find a solution.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Does your deployment server contains a directory with name 'C'

Comment: No it doesn't.  I'm trying to have the document saved to the users PC and I know I'm doing it incorrectly, just can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Comment: You can't just write a file to a client's computer from the server side. Have you ever seen a website work like that? Of course not, it'd be a massive security flaw if websites could do that. Instead, you can write the file to an HTTP response and the client can choose whether they want to download the file or not.

Comment: Yeah, like I said I’m new to this.  I was thinking it would do the file save pop up.

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure about what is causing the problem. But there is certainly a thing which may be causing PDF generation to fail. Never hardcode directory manually. Instead try to get it dynamically according to the server on which your web application is deployed

You can replace the directory code with

```
string desktopFolder = Path.GetFullPath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
string downloadFolder = desktopFolder + "\\Rate Confirmations";

if (!Directory.Exists(downloadFolder))
     Directory.CreateDirectory(downloadFolder);
```

This code will automatically get you application current directory and change it to absolute path from virtual path

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was hoping my issue was but unfortunately this did not fix it.

Comment: Its downloading correctly locally ? To download correctly ypu need to return stream as a response

Comment: You can't save directly anything to users pc instead you need to pass stream as API response